# StoredProcItemReader- procedure is returning two resultset

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-batch

I am using StoredProcItemReader in spring batch and my storedProcedure is returning two resultset. How can i get the result from both resultset in a single go/call. Can i set storedProcItemReader.setRefCursorPosition(<<1st resultset index>>) and storedProcItemReader.setRefCursorPosition(<<2nd resultset index>>) both.

As we can get the two resultset's result in normal java jdbc call like:-

```
CallableStatement cStmt = myConnect.prepareCall("{CALL sp_emps_in_dept(?)}");
cStmt.setInt(1, deptId);
cStmt.execute();
ResultSet rs1 = cStmt.getResultSet();
while (rs1.next()) 
  {
    // Result
  }
rs1.close();
/* process second result set */
if (cStmt.getMoreResults()) 
    {
      ResultSet rs2 = cStmt.getResultSet();
      while (rs2.next()) 
         {
            // 2nd Result 
         }
      rs2.close();
     }
cStmt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom `ItemReader` for this.  Spring Batch's `StoredProcedureItemReader` only supports reading from a single `ResultSet`.